# Qt: Rotate QGraphicsItem's children around themselves instead of parent

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I am a beginner in Qt and I'm looking for some help for a widget-based application... I have a QGraphicsItem with 3 identical children placed at different offsets. What I want to achieve is to synchronise transformations between parent and children. Currently, I use the setRotation function to achieve rotation but it rotates the children around the parent's centre of rotation. I can't find how to rotate each child around its own centre. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //setting up the window
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,600);
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->setFixedSize(800,600);

    //adding 2 squares (parent and child
    QGraphicsRectItem * parentItem= new QGraphicsRectItem(0,0,20,20);
    scene->addItem(parentItem);
    QGraphicsRectItem * childItem =new QGraphicsRectItem(0,0,20,20,parentItem);
    //moving child 100px to the right
    childItem->setPos(100,0);
    //childItem->setTransformOriginPoint(100,0);//uncomment to move child's centre of rotation

    //rotating 15 deg
    parentItem->setRotation(15);

    view->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: How did you move the items? Did you set their position, relative to parent, with `setPos`?

Comment: I tried setPos and moveBy... I also tried them in combination with setTransformOriginPoint to move the rotation centre. The rotation centre effectively gets moved but the setRotation function still uses the parent's centre.

Comment: Can you post a small, self-contained (single `main.cpp` file) test case that reproduces it? Set up and display a view on a scene, add two elements to the scene (parent with a child), and show how you move the child and apply the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason behind this: the absolute transformation is not really passed from parent to children like I thought. In fact, when you rotate the parent, only the coordinates base used by children gets rotated. **Simply put:** if you want to synchronise rotation between items, using the parent/child relation is not the right way to do it!